# cannot trigger ng-click on link element with jquery

Tags: javascript, angularjs, e2e-testing

I have this problem which I cannot solve and I have wasted all day trying to find a solution. I am writing automated end to end tests with jebb, I want to trigger the click even on this element

```
    <a class="btn-facebook btn-social-icon" ng-click="signIn()">
    <div class="ico_line"></div>
     <span class="icon-group-align ng-binding">
     Facebook Login
     </span>
    </a>
```

the problem is that $('.btn-facebook').click() works on ALL browsers except for Safari.

I have tried the following but none of it has worked:

1) used $('.btn-facebook')[0].click();
2) making a javascript event and dispatching this event on click
3) cursor: pointer for the a element

I have also added an href="#" which makes the click work but this is not desired behavior. It just confirms that the problem is with ng-click and not the element.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does `$('.btn-facebook').triggerHandler("click")` have the same problem?

Comment: yes triggerHandler also doesn't work